# Не могу запустить Киви

Tags: python, kivy

Скачал питон, потом `-m pip install kivy` и `cython`. `pygame` не нашло под сборку х64.
Запускаю пример из учебника... и результат на скриншоте. В чем проблема? Как запустить этот киви? Просто питоновские файлики работают на ура.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Попробуйте запускать с Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

1. Судя по ошибке в конце вывода (`ImportError`), *python* не может найти указанные библиотеки. Удостоверьтесь, что все компоненты *kivy* установлены [ПРАВИЛЬНО](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html). Заодно убедитесь, что всё, связанное с *python*, имеет одинаковую разрядность.
2. <del>У вас случайно кириллица не используется в примере (`UnicodeDecodeError`)? Из скриншота весь исходник не видно.</del>
3. UPD:

> И в начале всё-равно ошибку выдает. Как это можно исправить?

Судя по всему, что вы описали (`UnicodeDecodeError`), у вас может быть проблема с кодировкой по умолчанию. Попробуйте добавить в начале кода изменение дефолтной кодировки:

```
    import sys
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. А уточните, пожалуйста, как можно удостовериться в правильности установки компонентов? Есть какая-нибудь комманда или список?

Comment: @IvanPirognoe если вы выполнили все необходимые действия в [инструкции](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html), и у вас не возникло ошибок, то это и есть ответ, что компоненты *kivy* установлено правильно.

Answer (score 0):

После того, как выполнил этот шаг:

> ## . Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~90MB) if not needed, see Kivy’s dependencies):
>
> python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew \
>   kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/

остался только этот еррор

[image: Новые изменения]

Comment: Сложно ответить на вопрос, покажите исходный код вашего примера.

Сначала вы запускали скрипт *new_1.py*, там была строка `from kivy.app import App`. Теперь вы запускаете другой скрипт *kivy.py*, где, судя по скриншоту, есть строка `from app import App`. Определитесь.

Comment: Спасибо большое, @approximatenumber ! Запустилось с файлика new_1.py

Comment: Исправил свой ответ, попутно ответив на ваш вопрос. Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, можете пометить его правильным.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос - в коммандной строке всегда будет столько пунктов загружаться?

from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'error')

В командной строке будут выводиться только ошибки.

Answer (score -1):

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Код выше сработал и окошко запустилось. Вопрос - в коммандной строке всегда будет столько пунктов загружаться? И в начале всё-равно ошибку выдает. Как это можно исправить?
[image: Результат]